# React routing showing wrong page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to figure out react routing but the routes are still showing the home page instead of the designated page. So when a user uses the route /howto the howto.tsx file's html shows. Right now when you go to /howto it shows the html from _App.tsx. There are also no errors in the console.
`index.tsx`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import MyApp from './_app';
import HowTo from './howto';
  
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <Router>
           <div className="App">
            <ul className="App-header">
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/howto">How to</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
           <Routes>
                 <Route path='/' element={< MyApp />}></Route>
                 <Route path='/howto' element={< HowTo />}></Route>
          </Routes>
          </div>
       </Router>
   );
  }
}
  
export default App;
```

`_app.tsx`

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import Link from 'next/link'

import '../styles/globals.css'

const MyApp = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-[50vh]">
        <p className="text-black text-9xl">
          Beebate
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-[10vh]">
        <Link href="/howto">
          <button
            onClick={() => {}}
            className="bg-[#FF5C00] opacity-70 h-[10vh] w-[20vh] text-3xl rounded-xl"
          >
            Continue
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: could u show the code from howto?

Comment: I don't see any issue with *this* specific code. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] and exact steps to reproduce any issue?

Comment: import Link from 'next/link'
but its routed via react-router-dom try importing Link from react-router-dom

Comment: oh wait is that a nextjs? throw out the react-router-dom if so hes not needed in a next app

Comment: Yes it is Next, and how should I use routes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js uses the file system to enable routing in the app.
Next automatically treats every file with the extensions .js, .jsx, .ts, or .tsx under the pages directory as a route. So no react-router-dom is required. Thats most likely the problem. nextjs is confused and react-router-dom overwrites the existing routes.

```
            <div>
                <h1>Home Page</h1>
                <Link href='/article'>
                    <a>Articles</a>
                </Link>
                <br/>
                <Link href='/book'>
                    <a>Books</a>
                </Link>
            </div>
```

Something like that does the job already

heres another example

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={"howto"}>click me</Link>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this is actually everything you would need to route. i would stay with conventions to name the function Home since it is used outside. you dont need to import anything

Comment: I removed the file and the library but /howto is still showing _app.tsx instead of howto.tsx

Comment: edited the question since the index should something like above. and keep in mind that your filepath is also your url means pages/folder/maybeAnotherFolder/File so "./someSubfolder/AnotherFolder/howto.tsx" would result in href="someSubfolder/AnotherFolder/howto"

Comment: @Devium https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/routing-in-nextjs-beginners-guide/ has a pretty fast and well explained tutorial to it. Can recommend it

Comment: I followed the tutorial but 1. I can't import globals.css if I rename _app.tsx to index.tsx and two /howto still shows _app.tsx instead of howto.tsx

Comment: @Devium you need both _app.tsx and index.tsx!

Comment: @Devium i would recommend you to stop in your current project and start in a new project with npx create-next-app@latest (this also gives u the basic folder structure) so that you can get a better overall impression from nextjs